# View is throwing StringBuilder out of memory exception

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, out-of-memory, stringbuilder

Our team is using a ASP.NET MVC with C# to generate a very complex grid of data. It initially worked fine, but when we created a realistic but large load of data to test scaling, we constantly find ourselves encountering a StringBuilder out of memory exception. I imagine that the response we are building is many megs of data, but maybe on the order of 5-10 MB of data, not 100s or 1000s.

I've tried inserting Garbage Collection into the Razor view to see if maybe cleaning up unused objects would yield a contiguous segment of memory to work with, but this has been unsuccessful. I've optimized the use of Linq queries on the object model, but this has only served to speed up how fast we see the exception.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way I can tell the framework how large I need a stringbuilder to be for constructing the response? I have no ability to decrease the size of the page's content, as it's an approved requirement that has been in production for some time. Is there another way to perhaps break up the issue into separate partial views that might remove this exception?

Due the sensitivity of the system, I'm afraid I'm unable to post any code relevant to my question, but hopefully I've posted sufficient information that someone may assist. The system is .NET MVC 4.0, NHibernate, SQL Server, javascript/jquery. The only issue we seem to be having is with the rendering of already retrieved data though, so .NET MVC 4.0 should be the only relevant factor.

Comment: Is the exception occurring in the framework code, or in your application code? Can you post at least an anonymized stack-trace?

Comment: You're going to have to create a [mcve].

Comment: I can post a little, but not much.

"An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code"

Inner Exception:    at System.Text.StringBuilder.ExpandByABlock(Int32 minBlockCharCount)
 .... going all the way back to my layout file that is calling renderBody()

It appears that maybe my code gets through rendering the view, but when assigning it to the layout page it is breaking?

Comment: either get more RAM on the server or development machine (wherever the error was thrown), or implement paging with subsequent calls to get the new page data.  Garbage Collection at  this stage would only slow things down and make matters worse, as there's nothing to clean up.

Comment: Dev box has 32 GB of RAM. We are running out far sooner than that.